# PhoneGap 3.3.0 - Getting error code 1 "FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR" when downloading file to mobile device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, download

I am working on an old Phonegap project which is using Phonegap version 3.3.0. I am trying to download a file to my mobile device. However, I'm am getting error code 1 "FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR".

I checked several times and the file path is absolutely correct and it is downloadable. So, its not the issue of the source file. However, now, I am doubting whether it might be the destination path that is causing this. I've set the destination as "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/".

```
requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileTransfer.download("https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_2x.png", "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.png", function (theFile) {
//success
}, function (error) {
//ERROR - CURRENTLY THE CODE HERE IS EXECUTED
});
}, function fail(evt) {
//COULD NOT GET THE FILESYSTEM
});
```